# Bash Script to select a file and run the first instance of it

Tags: php, bash

I am trying to write a small bash script which will select the first instance of phpize and run it. Basically, i have 2 versions of PHP installed on my server - One installed via yum and the other compiled from source. Thus, I have 3 occurrences of phpize (the one from yum, the one compiled from source and the one in the source itself).

I have a bash script which navigated into the source of ffmpeg-php but I need to phpize it first. i  know we can use the find command like so:

```
find / -name phpize
```

But any idea how to read it into a variable and then run the variable as a command?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `find` has an option called `-exec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the variable as the first word in a command and it will run it as a program:

```
var=$(find / -name phpize | head -1) # Get first occurrence
"$var" arguments
```

Comment: I haven't coded in PHP and hence this question - does it make a difference which _phpize_ I use (as I said there are 2 versions of PHP installed)?